# Is there point in using Sessions in this particular case?

Tags: asp.net, session, query-string, session-state

The client opens a website through a non-web app and thus gives an ID and a unique security code through query strings. So the url looks smth like this: `.../Default.aspx?uI=21&sc=b2r#67!kl`

For different clients, the website has different content. The users are not more than 10 (considering that 1 client is 1 company that has many employees(users) and for all users of 1 company the security code is the same). So 10 users from the same company will have different IDs (`uI`) but the same security code (`sc`) and so on for the different companies.

So is there point in using Sessions or it is sufficient to use just the query string values for distinguishing the users? Why/why not?

Suggestion of any other, better way of implementation is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that having the URL hold information like UserID's and a security code is not a good idea.

Maybe you could make a 'landing page' where you still pass in this information in a query string, on that page set 2 session variables one for UserID and the other security code. Redirect to the default page without the query strings. Then anytime you need to check the variables you can through session, and without having the querystring showing. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Using QueryString users could manipulate the resulting output using location bar and changing SC or UI. That may produce undesired output while navigating form one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you are trying to pass in a unique identifier for a user you might want to look at passing in a secure token in the URL perhaps a GUID that is a unique combination for the User/Security Code.  Then on the back end validate this token and then use ASP.NET Membership to handle storing the user's credentials.

See below for more information on membership:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx